# Android Buttons behind tabs are getting selected instead of the one in the selected tab

Tags: android, tabs, kotlin, onclicklistener

I'm facing a weird and unexpected behaviour. I have an Android app built in kotlin 1.2.50 targeting vs 27 (min 24) that is using several tabs. 
On SectionsPagerAdapter getItem I am returning a different fragment that contains a list of buttons into a table layout. The problem is that when I click on a button the clicked event is raised by a non visible tab. The top most button setOnClickListener in the visible tab is not fired

Comment: can you add an image to illustrate your problem better?

Comment: @HawkPriest. At the moment I am keeping all buttons in one tab to do some progress. I will try to take small recording later on. Thanks